# Alamofire called twice

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to use Alamofire but it`s really weird.
I'm calling this function and debugging, it's being called twice, I don't know why.

In the first time it just jump all the function without doing anything and the second time runs normaly.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    download{
        //do stuffs
    }

}

func download(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete){

    Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request ?? "")  // original URL request
        print(response.response ?? "") // HTTP URL response
        print(response.data ?? "")     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }
        completed()
    }
}
```

This ViewController it's being called by a PerformSegue WithIdentifier. I don't know what could be.

Comment: call perform segue inside this if : if let JSON = response.result.value {
            //Call here perform segue                                                 
           print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        } Because it is async call

Comment: What function is being called twice? Since the request is asynchronous, it is expected that it will run `.request` once and then a second later actually run the content of the block. If possible, put `print` in different places in your code and show the results.

Comment: The     "Alamofire.request"
It looks like running twice.

Comment: Does it print twice?

Comment: Is your `viewDidLoad` method called more than twice? Try putting `print("viewDidLoad")` directly in the beginning of the `viewDidLoad` function.

Answer (score 2):

It could be the debug statements itself causing the extra request. For example if you do something like this to see what the request will look like then it will actually make the request

```
let test = session.request(url);

print("Debug print request")
// this will make first call even though response is not handled
debugPrint(test)

// second call
session.request(url).responseJson....
```

Comment: Wow! I would like to know more about this, could you explain why is performing the request again when you try to print something? Or do you have links where I can take a look deeper? Thank you!

**edit**
This resolved my problem, removing statements such as `print("invokedURL: \(request.urlRequest?.url?.absoluteString)")` from the code reduce the duplication of the request. Now it's getting called once but I'm still wondering why works like that.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are putting a break point on the request line. When you do this its gonna trigger twice. First time when request is sended and second time when you get the response. Compiler sees the completion block as 1 line and triggers on the same line again.

Answer (score 0):

Check on your storyboard (Connection Inspector, ⌘ + ⌥ + 6) if there are no duplicated old connections.

Comment: There is no duplicates :/